# nuxt axios.post request with empty body

Tags: express, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get nuxt with axios working.
I do the following post request (store/index.js):

```
login({ commit }, { username, password }) {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    password
  , username
  })
  console.log('store login ', username, password)
  this.$axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', data)  
  .then(res => {
    commit('SET_USER', res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
  })
}
```

My backend looks like this (api/auth.js):

```
const express           = require('express')
const session           = require('express-session')
const body_parser       = require('body-parser')
const app               = express()
const router            = express.Router()

app.use(body_parser.json())
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('try to login ', req.body)
  if (!req.body)
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'No body' })
  if (req.body.username === 'demo' && req.body.password === 'demo') {
    req.session.auth_user = { username: 'demo' }
    console.log('logged in')
    return res.json({ username: 'demo' })
  }
  res.status(401).json({ message: 'Bad credentials' })
})
```

My Problem is, that the req.body is always undefined. But in the error message I can see, that the params are sent. (config.data)

[image]

Does anybody has an idea what I'm missing? I use body-parser and checked everything 100 times. I guess it's something total obvious, but I can't see it.

My nuxt.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  , '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },
  serverMiddleware: ['@api/auth']
  ...
}
```

Comment: Afaik you dont need to stringify you dict before passing it to post

Answer (score 0):

Probably you take this error also. This is caused by cors policy.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/.......' from
>   origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

same problem occured on my project.

in server index.js change line

```
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost'
```

and nuxt.config.js

```
axios: {
baseURL: 'http://localhost:YOUR_PORT'
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define bodyParser in router.

```js
router.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).